# How to reverse the operation of torch.nn.functional.grid_sample?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

If we get two images, target image `tgt_img` and source image `src_img`. And, we also know the grid `grid` from source image to target image. Thus, we can use the F.grid_sample to generate target image from source image.

```
tgt_img = F.grid_sample(src_img, grid)
```

Is there any good idea to get the `inv_grid` that are from target image to source image. So that:

```
inv_grid = ?
src_img =  F.grid_sample(tgt_img, inv_grid)
```

I have tried to read the data in grid and generate a inv_grid, but I want to know if there any better and faster method

Here is an example, a `grid` is given as is shown below:
[a grid that represent the coordinates correspondence from src_img to tgt_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USTQ0.png)

Then I want to use this grid to generate the inv_grid, which represent the coordinates correspondence from tgt_img to src_img. The result are shown here:
[tgt_img to src_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L05aQ.png)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you created `grid` in the first place.
If `grid` was created using [`F.affine_grid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.affine_grid), then you simply need to create `inv_grid` using the inverse of `theta` - the affine transformation used to create `grid`.
In a more general case, `grid` might not have `inv_grid` at all! Suppose `grid` maps several `src_img` pixels to the same `tgt_img` pixel - how can you invert this singularity?

Comment: Grid represents the correspondence between the coordinates of `src_img` and `tgt_img`.  Since we know this correspondence, we can generate the `inv_grid`.
For example, `tgt_img[0,0]` supposed to be sampled from `src_img[1,3]`. Then in contrary, `src_img[1,3]` can be sampled from `tgt_img[0,0]`.

Comment: I want to know how to achieve this transform quickly. Here is an example:
`[[[1,-1],[0,-1],[-1,-1]],
[[1, 0],[0, 0],[-1, 0]],
[[1, 1],[0, 1],[-1, 1]]]`

then we can get the `inv_grid`:
`[[[-1,1],[0,1],[1,1]],
[[-1,0],[0,0],[1,0]],
[[-1,-1],[0,-1],[1,-1]]]
`
sorry for that I am new to stack overflow and I don't know how to insert images and  make the comment look better.

Comment: @glhua - you cannot insert images in comments - but you **can** edit your question and add images and diagrams there.